# How do I limit the results of Intellij Find Usages to only those of a specific class?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am a new user to Intellij. I have a hierarchy where both ClassA and ClassB implement foo() in MyInterface:

```java
public interface MyInterface{
    void foo()
}
```

```java
public class ClassA implements MyInterface{
    @Override
    public void foo(){
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

```java
public class ClassB implements MyInterface{
    @Override
    public void foo(){
        System.out.println("World");
    }
}
```

```java
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args){
         new ClassA().foo();
         new ClassB().foo();
    }
}
```

When I do Find Usages on the foo() definition in ClassA, both the foo() from ClassA and ClassB are found. Is there a way to only have the foo() called on the ClassA instance found?

Comment: You can open ClassA.java and then find foo() on this file only.

Comment: The find in files dialog already does what you need, [see here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/finding-and-replacing-text-in-project.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can search for usages of only ClassA:
[image]

Also you can restrict usages [scope](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/scope.html) to certain files in project (including creating your custom scope):
[image]